# How to re-load a saved model (with graph?) to create the same results on future testing data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have trained a model and saved all the files (meta, index, checkpoint, etc.) using the `saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()` function, and now I want to re-load that model in order to test on new data. It works fine, but my question is, every time I run the restored model on the same dataset (i.e. run it once on a testing dataset, and then start it over and run it again on that same dataset) I get very different results. I'm hoping to be able to run it over and over again on the same dataset, but get the same results.

I have two separate .py files, one for training and one for testing/loading the model to test on the dataset. My training variables/placeholders look something like this in the training.py file (in case it's relevant):

```
    # set some tensorflow variables and placeholders, etc.
    self.X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, self.state_size))                                                                  
    self.REWARDS = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None))
    self.ACTIONS = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
    feed_forward = tf.layers.dense(self.X, self.LAYER_SIZE, activation = tf.nn.relu)
    self.logits = tf.layers.dense(feed_forward, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, activation = tf.nn.softmax)
    input_y = tf.one_hot(self.ACTIONS, self.OUTPUT_SIZE)
    loglike = tf.math.log((input_y * (input_y - self.logits) + (1 - input_y) * (input_y + self.logits)) + 1) # tf.log
    rewards = tf.tile(tf.reshape(self.REWARDS, (-1,1)), [1, self.OUTPUT_SIZE])
    self.cost = -tf.reduce_mean(loglike * (rewards + 1)) # leave this as a negative, so that the minimize function of the Adam optimizer will keep improving 
    # Adam Optimizer
    self.optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = self.LEARNING_RATE).minimize(self.cost) # minimize(self.cost)
    # Start the Tensorflow session
    self.sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()
    self.sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
...
            saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
            save_path = saver.save(self.sess, "./agent_output/" + name + "_model")
```

And in the testing.py file, it looks something like this:

```
    ...
    # Start the Tensorflow session
    self.sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()

    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./agent_output/' + name + '_model.meta')
    new_saver.restore(self.sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./agent_output/'))
    print('Model loaded step 1')

    #saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    #saver.restore(self.sess, "./agent_output/" + name + "_model")
    #print('Model Restored!')

    self.sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
```

Just to give you an idea of what I'm working with. As you can see, I've tried the import_meta_graph and the commented out `saver.restore` method, but I think I'm missing something, or if it's even possible in my case?

I'm just hoping someone can point me in the right direction. What I've discovered on my own is that there should be a way to not only load the variables, but also the graph? Or maybe I need to implement that during the training? I'm running Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 1.14 (I believe? Not 2.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably running `self.sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())` after restoring the model. You only need to run this for a fresh model not a restored one. Try it without this line.

Comment: That worked! And I used the saver.restore() function to load the model back in, not the import_meta_graph. Thanks a million!